# How to do svn update without password on crontab

Tags: 13.04, ssh, password, cron, svn

I'm new to svn and ssh. I'm trying to do svn update of 5 repositories in my local system every 3 hours on crontab.
So, to achieve this I have setup `ssh passwordless login` using the below steps:
1. `ssh-keygen`
2. `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub test@repo.test.in`
3. I did `ssh test@repo.test.in`
Till here it works fine for me. I'm able to login without password.
But, when I try to do `sudo svn update` on the 5 repositories, it is propmpting for password. 
How to make svn update without password. Is there any way that I can do update of the repositories every 3 hours on cron.
I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205149/automating-svn-update), but could not get it.
I'm using

```
`Ubuntu version : Ubuntu 13.04`         
OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that since you use `sudo`, the `svn update` command is executed as `root`, so the `~/.ssh` directory of your normal user is not taken into account.

If you have to do the `svn update` as root, then you should also perform the steps 1 and 2 that you described as root, i.e., with `sudo`. But only do this id you are very aware of what you are doing.

If it is possible for you to do all those svn updates as a normal user, that would be a much better way. In that case, simply remove the `sudo` and only execute the command `svn update` as a cronjob. Additionally, you will also have to run the cronjob as a normal user. Refer to this answer here to learn how to execute cronjobs as a normal user:

https://superuser.com/questions/170866/how-to-run-a-cron-job-as-a-specific-user

In you case, you would probably want something like this in `/etc/crontab`:

```
 00 */3   * * *   yourusername   cd /some/path/ && svn update
```

Replace `yourusername` with the username of the user that generated the SSH keypair and copied the public key to `test@repo.test.in`, and `/some/path/` with the path to your local copy of the svn repo you want to check out.

Answer (score 1):

Any command run with `sudo` (without further arguments) will be run as root. root does not have access to your SSH keys, thus your passwordless login setup fails.

If your setup works when you run it with your own user, the fix is easy. In order to run the svn updates in a cronjob, but with your user, try using the `-u` option.

```
sudo -u yourusername svn update
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly simple one...

```
sudo svn update
```

## *WHHHYY?!!?!!*

I'm not sure I need to say anything else but just to bulk out the answer a bit more... Running as sudo means you're running as root. Which means your local `~/.ssh/`  configuration counts for zip.

It also means that all the files created are owned by root. Uneditable by your user. And this is why (repeat this bit out aloud) ***we never use `sudo` with subversion***. It's unneccessary and it's harmful.

To fix this, I'd suggest wiping out your local copy (as long as you have a backup) and then checking out a new copy as your user. And in your crontab, just omit the `sudo`.